# how to parse watch command output to last 5 digits?

Tags: regex

From the command

> watch -n1 "ifconfig eth0 | grep GiB". I have output given below,

Now i just want the last 5 digits before (GiB). I wrote an regex for it, and it seems to [work](http://www.rubular.com/r/fQHTdkCKLI)

> (\d{1,4})(?!.*\d)\sGiB

The only problem is that i cannot use it with the command i showed above? I'm using ubuntu any help

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't parse the watch command, you'd parse whatever command watch was running. I pimped your search to match a wider range of possible output from ifconfig:

```
$ ifconfig eth0 | grep -Eo '[0-9\.]+ [PTGMK]i?B'
164.8 GB
142.6 GB
```

This is made possible by grep's `-E` argument which allows a wider syntax and `-o` which only outputs matching strings.

If you want to loop that, you can but you have to wrap it in a shell so the pipe is interpreted correctly:

```
watch -x sh -c "ifconfig eth0 | grep -Eo '[0-9\.]+ [PTGMK]i?B'"
```

But in my opinion, this isn't wildly useful as it is... `watch` is really only good for a real person watching the screen. If that's the case, you're all done but if you want to do something with these numbers on a regular basis, you're probably using the wrong tool.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm using watch for one time basis, I'm considering using iptraf in future i ran your command but i don't think its giving me any changes in real time basis?

Comment: Yeah, it'll update every two seconds. Obviously, once you're up to GiB, you need to shift a fair amount of traffic before it'll change.

Comment: I'm not sure what does sh -c does, seems like a counter, the difference i'm getting this command is that i cannot see per sec changes to the output like i can do in the original command. The traffic I'm getting is about 30 Mb/s its span port traffic.

Comment: `sh -c "..."` is a way of running multiple commands that would otherwise be interpreted outside of that shell, together. Here it allows me to pipe the internal output of `ifconfig` through `grep`. The sh command is being run every 2 seconds (`watch`'s default) and in turn, sh runs the command we give it. If you want it to be every second, stick a `-n1` in after the `-x`.

Comment: (And this is tested. It works. I've just sat and watched the numbers while around while I did a test with `iperf`)

Comment: for me adding -x switch gives me syntax error ; i think that switch is not supported in my version of watch. I think i was not be able to explain my position in form of live example. This is how i want my screen to look after the command runs. http://www.rubular.com/r/xaf0yx7hTZ